# C# Add lists to Oracle user defined type

Tags: c#, oracle, list

I have two Oracle user defined type object

```
T_CODE_LIST_TABLE 
T_CODE_LIST
```

I can add new  T_CODE_LIST to  T_CODE_LIST_TABLE 
As below

```
T_CODE_LIST_TABLE t_code_list_tab = new T_CODE_LIST_TABLE();

t_code_list_tab.Value = new T_CODE_LIST[] {
        new T_CODE_LIST() { TEAMID = "1", GROUPTYPE = "1", GROUPLOGIC = "1", GROUPVALUE = val1.ToString()},
        new T_CODE_LIST() { TEAMID = "2", GROUPTYPE = "2", GROUPLOGIC = "2", GROUPVALUE = val2.ToString()},
        new T_CODE_LIST() { TEAMID = "3", GROUPTYPE  = "3", GROUPLOGIC = "3”,GROUPVALUE = val3.ToString()}          
 };
```

But I want it to be able to add  as many T_CODE_LIST()  as a user needs during run time like below, how can I do that?

```
t_code_list_tab.Value = new T_CODE_LIST[] {
        new T_CODE_LIST() { TEAMID = "1", GROUPTYPE = "1", GROUPLOGIC = "1", GROUPVALUE = val1.ToString()},
        new T_CODE_LIST() { TEAMID = "2", GROUPTYPE = "2", GROUPLOGIC = "2", GROUPVALUE = val2.ToString()},
        new T_CODE_LIST() { TEAMID = "3", GROUPTYPE  = "3", GROUPLOGIC = "3”,GROUPVALUE = val3.ToString()},
.
.
.
N times
.
.
.

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by many approaches. Adding value in array dynamically is not straightforward.
One of the better solution can be create list then add objects. Whenever needed convert it to array using .ToArray() function.

You code can be as below

```
List<T_CODE_LIST> tcodes =new List<T_CODE_LIST>();
tcodes.Add(new T_CODE_LIST() { TEAMID = "1", GROUPTYPE = "1", GROUPLOGIC = "1", GROUPVALUE = val1.ToString()});
.
.
....N times ...whenever needed

T_CODE_LIST_TABLE t_code_list_tab = new T_CODE_LIST_TABLE();
t_code_list_tab.Value = tcodes.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, ANaik! I tried your method. But there is red line showing the error as “The name ‘tcode.Add’ does not exist in the current context. The name ‘tcode’ does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Have imported the respective namespace?

Comment: Have u imported the respective namespace?  System.Collections.Generic. one more thing please use 'tcodes' and not 'tcode' if it is declared as tcodes.

Comment: Yes,I used ‘tcode’ as I declared, imported System.Collections.Generic

Comment: It strange, why tcodes is giving you this error. but for your reference i have created one runable project on dotnetfiddle (online .net compiler project). You can run and check output it is not throwing any error. check this https://dotnetfiddle.net/YpnSYR

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to this is resize array size whenever needed, depending on items to be added in array.

You can check this example of [MSDN Resize Array](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051.aspx#Examples)

I hope this helps.

Comment: You are right. It’s strange. The first approach is the best one if it work. I will find out why It didn’t work.